# ¿Como arrancar un script PHP usando un jpeg/png como extension?

Tags: php, apache

Lo que hago es lo siguiente creo un `.php` que tendrá como extension `.png` o `.jpg` el que se supone a mostrar la imagen, pero no me muestra nada:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo "<img src='".$valor."logo.jpg' border='0' width='300' height='100'>";  
echo 'test';
?>
```

Después pongo en mi `.htaccess` lo siguiente:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .png
AddType application/x-httpd-php .png
```

Pero cuando abro mi imagen `.png` lo primero no me muestra la imagen subida a mi servidor, por lo que no se arranca mi PHP, por ejemplo:

http://hostingdelavera.260mb.net/image.png

La otra imagen sería logo que es la siguiente:

[la imagen](http://hostingdelavera.260mb.net/logo.jpg)

¿Como podría hacer para que mi PHP se ejecutara con la extension `.png` o `.jpg`? Ya que parece que no lo hace.

Y segundo muestre la imagen.

Imagen del servidor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El .htaccess oculto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haz probado con `Content-type: text/html`?

Comment: no funciono con text/html pero subi una captura

Comment: @OmarOmar ingreso a la url `http://hostingdelavera.260mb.net/image.png` y me muestra una imagen con el texto `test`. HTML: `<img src='logo.jpg' border='0' width='300' height='100'>test`

Comment: fue un error por mi parte el navegador chrome me mostraba lo mismo por el cache probe a abrir una ventana privada y me mostro correctamente la foto con un fondo blanco. Pero solo se puede como texto entonces si pongo Content-type: image/png como imagen no se podría? Eb caso de usar text/html funciona bien tienes razón. Una pregunta como pones en gris cuando comentas??

Comment: @OmarOmar para un encabezado HTTP se usa `Content-Type: text/html`, en el caso para una imagen PNG es `Content-type: image/png`. Podrías revisa [Creación de un PNG con PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/image.examples-png.php) como [Encabezados HTTP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php). Para resaltar un texto en el comentario, abajo de **Añadir comentario** hay una opción llamada **ayuda**.

Comment: `ok` vale lo entendi disculpa por lo del comentario si supongo que no habré echo correctamente en el encabezado por lo que no se muestra lo revisaré disculpa por las molestias! estaba  un poco aturdido!